# Initialize IcacheManager in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, abp

Can someone please guide me on how I can create instance of the below class that has ICacheManager Inject constructor. Since am new to this, not sure what type of parameter I have to pass when instantiating the below class to the constructor.

```
class RedisOperation : AbpModule
{
    private readonly string CacheKey = "RedisPOC";
    
    private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;

    public RedisOperation()
    { }
    public RedisOperation(ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        _cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }
    
    public async void SetValueInCache(string input)
    {
        var lstInputs = await _cacheManager.GetCache(CacheKey).GetOrDefaultAsync(CacheKey);
        List<string> cacheInputStringList = new List<string>();

        if(lstInputs != null)            
            cacheInputStringList = (List<string>)lstInputs;
            
        cacheInputStringList.Add(input);
        await _cacheManager.GetCache(CacheKey).SetAsync(CacheKey, cacheInputStringList);                        
    }

    public async void ClearCache()
    {
        var lstInputs = await _cacheManager.GetCache(CacheKey).GetOrDefaultAsync(CacheKey);            

        if (lstInputs != null)
            await _cacheManager.GetCache(CacheKey).ClearAsync();
    }
}
```

}

Now am trying to create instance of the above class, in main method as below,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        RedisOperation redisOp = new RedisOperation();  ==> Need to know how the ICacheManager object to be passed to the constructor to create the instance.



        Console.WriteLine("Redis Cache POC");

        Console.WriteLine("Choose below option to perform operation on RedisCache");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Add");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Clear");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        switch(int.Parse(input))
        {
            case 1:
                string inputText = Console.ReadLine();
                redisOp.SetValueInCache(inputText);
                break;
            case 2:
                redisOp.ClearCache();
                break;

        }            

    }
```

Comment: Is this the ABP cachemanager or your own implementation?

Comment: @klekmek, its ABP cachemanager. I ave used it in my class RedisOperation. Am trying to create instance of RedisOperation in another class to use the methods defined in this class. So when creating object i need to pass parameter to this constructor so that Icachemanager is initialized. Not sure of the parameter to be passed.

Comment: I'd suggest you read up on Dependency Injection. ABP also has it's own implementation of redis cache, might be wiser to use that.

Comment: [docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.3/Dependency-Injection#injecting-dependencies](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/5.3/Dependency-Injection#injecting-dependencies)

Comment: @klekmek, I have updated my code in the question. Am using the rediscache implmentation methos get/set/clear. Can you please let me know where am wrong

Comment: Follow @aaron his advice. You are trying to instantiate an object directly, however ABP uses the Dependency Injection pattern. Read up how that pattern works and you will get a far better answer.